# d3 Ordinal Scale - using map function to label ticks, but it will not map correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to set up a fairly basic bar chart with D3.  I seemed to grasp ordinal scales (or so I thought), but the map function is not mapping correctly.  (it is like it's mapping to a reversed array, and not my actual array)

here is the sample data:

```
[
  {
    "ShipCountry": "USA",
    "Column1": 169209.9000
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Germany",
    "Column1": 140173.0500
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Austria",
    "Column1": 91793.2900
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Brazil",
    "Column1": 60623.8400
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "France",
    "Column1": 52713.6700
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Sweden",
    "Column1": 40032.4400
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "UK",
    "Column1": 36697.6900
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Venezuela",
    "Column1": 34051.4900
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Ireland",
    "Column1": 33649.7800
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Canada",
    "Column1": 27229.1000
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Denmark",
    "Column1": 17047.1000
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Switzerland",
    "Column1": 16902.8000
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Belgium",
    "Column1": 15716.3000
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Mexico",
    "Column1": 14255.1800
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Finland",
    "Column1": 11570.3800
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Italy",
    "Column1": 10637.7300
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Spain",
    "Column1": 10591.3100
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Portugal",
    "Column1": 8152.2200
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Argentina",
    "Column1": 7276.9500
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Norway",
    "Column1": 3413.0000
  },
  {
    "ShipCountry": "Poland",
    "Column1": 2112.8200
  }
]
```

and here is my chart code-

```
function createChart(chartData) {


    var margin = { top: 10, bottom: 30, left: 65, right: 50 };

    var width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var padding = 0;

    //svg for chart with margins
    var svg = d3.select('#chart-wrapper')
                    .append('svg')
                        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .append('g')
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    //xScale will be based on ShipCountry attribute
    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(chartData.map(function(d) { return d.ShipCountry; }))
                                                                .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

    //yScale based on Freight
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(chartData, function (d) {
                                                                    return d.Column1;
                                                                })])
                                                                .range([height, 0]);

    //axis

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom');
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left').ticks(10);

    svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(chartData)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
            .attr('x', function (d, i) {
                return xScale(d.ShipCountry);
            })
            .attr('y', function (d) {
                return height - yScale(d.Column1);
            })
            .attr('height', function (d) {                    
                return yScale(d.Column1);
            })
            .attr('width', function (d) {
                return xScale.rangeBand();
            })
            .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
```

}

and here are the results (basically, Poland has US numbers and US has polands number
EDIT: I don't have enough rep to post a picture, only 2 away, will post screen shot of chart as soon as I can

Comment: In the chart, Poland is the tick for the highest bar, when it should be the the US.  US tick is under the smallest bar, which should be Poland.  It's like it mapped to the reverse array

Comment: The problem is that you're (implicitly) sorting the bars by their values, but you're not sorting the labels accordingly. If you position the bars by their index (not value) it should work fine. You could also sort the labels.